# The CSRF cookie value did not match the CSRF parameter value

Tags: content-editor, security, csrf

I got an error while clicking the item in Sitecore, but when I refreshed the page, I was able to click the item this time.

Exception:

```
Sitecore.Security.AntiCsrf.Exceptions.PotentialCsrfException
Message: The CSRF cookie value did not match the CSRF parameter value.
Source: Sitecore.Security.AntiCsrf
at Sitecore.Security.AntiCsrf.SitecoreAntiCsrfModule.RaiseError(Exception ex, HttpContext context)
at Sitecore.Security.AntiCsrf.SitecoreAntiCsrfModule.PreRequestHandlerExecute(Object sender, EventArgs e)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Comment: the link you shared doesn`t have any proper solution to work it in the normal browser , i am working on a prod server , and don`t have any extensions or fiddler there

Comment: Any chance the server was restarted in the meantime after you open Content Editor and before you clicked the item in Sitecore?

Comment: no , i dont think so , if the server would restarted (as you said) , i have be thrown out of the server . but that was not in my case , i just refreshed the page there and then only , and was able to click

Comment: It doesn't matter if the other post has or has not a proper solution. We still need to collect at least 1 good answer to any 1 question on this Q&A database, this is not a chat forum,.